# ActionView::Template::Error for form field in production (heroku) only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I get the following error when running my application in heroku but it works perfectly in development on my local system.  The result field was recently added to the database.  I ran heroku rake db:migrate and saw the new fields being added but the error still persists.  It looks like the model wasn't updated to handle the new field.

```
2011-08-25T00:27:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `result' for #<Test_result:0x0000000405d080>):
2011-08-25T00:27:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-08-25T00:27:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:            <td><%= f.association :project, :include_blank => false %></td>
2011-08-25T00:27:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <tr>
2011-08-25T00:27:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   </tr>
2011-08-25T00:27:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:           <td><%= f.input :result, :collection => ["Pass", "Fail"], :include_blank => false %></td>
2011-08-25T00:27:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:   </tr>
2011-08-25T00:27:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:           <td></td>
2011-08-25T00:27:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:   <tr class="bvt_app_white">
```

The actual form code is as follows:

```
   <%= simple_form_for(@test_result) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
   <table class="bvt_app_form_table">
        <tr class="bvt_app_white">
        <td><%= f.input :date_run, :label => "Date" %></td>
        <td><%= f.association :project, :include_blank => false %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.input :result, :collection => ["Pass", "Fail"], :include_blank => false %></td>
        <td></td>

</tr>
    <tr class="bvt_app_white">
        <td><%= f.input :server_rev, :input_html => {:size => 15, :maxlength => 15} %></td>
        <td><%= f.input :client_rev, :input_html => {:size => 15, :maxlength => 15} %></td>
    </tr>
<tr class="bvt_app_white">  
            <td><%= f.input :number_tests, :as => :string, :input_html => {:size => 8, :maxlength => 6} %></td>
            <td><%= f.input :number_passed, :as => :string, :input_html => {:size => 8, :maxlength => 6} %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bvt_app_white">
        <td><%= f.input :number_failed, :as => :string, :input_html => {:size => 8, :maxlength => 6} %></td>
        <td><%= f.input :actual_failed, :as => :string, :input_html => {:size => 8, :maxlength => 6} %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bvt_app_white">
<td colspan=2><%= f.input :false_neg, :as => :string, :label => "False Negatives", :input_html => {:size => 8, :maxlength => 6} %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bvt_app_white">
        <td colspan=2><%= f.input :comments %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bvt_app_white">
        <td><%= f.input :send_email, :as => :radio %></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Process Result" %>    
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you run your migrations? Is the result field present in the heroku db?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?